# How to get the Advantage Database data in ASP.net MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, advantage-database-server

I'm in Asp.net MVC3 environment, and I use Advantage Database 9.1.

and I want to get the Advantage Database data in Asp.net (+Repository pattern)

My Advantage Database has WebOrderHd table and I want to get the PK field of the table and count it.

(Table Name : WebOrderHd  Field Name : PK (character(36))

I think I connect to DB server successfully but I can not get the data.

here is my codes,

**Web.config**

```
<add name="EFAdsContext" connectionString="Data Source=\\XXX.XX.XX.XX:6262\DB_BACK\SD.ADD;ServerType=REMOTE;User ID=AdsSys;Password=xxxxx"
         providerName="Advantage.Data.Provider" />
```

**/Concrete/EFAdsContext.cs**

```
public class EFAdsContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<WebOrderHd> weborderhd { get; set; }
}
```

**/Concrete/EFWebOrderHdRepository.cs**

```
public class EFWebOrderHdRepository : IWebOrderHdRepository
{
    private EFAdsContext context = new EFAdsContext();

    public IQueryable<WebOrderHd> WebOrderHd
    {
        get { return context.weborderhd; }
    }
}
```

**/Abstract/IWebOrderHdRepository.cs**

```
public interface IXcartOrdersRepository
{
    IQueryable<XcartOrder> XcartOrders { get; }
}
```

**/Entities/WebOrderHd.cs**

```
public class WebOrderHd
{
    [Key]
    public string PK { get; set; }
    //public string ORDERNO { get; set; }
}
```

And In my **controller**,

```
IWebOrderHdRepository WebOrderHdRepository = new EFWebOrderHdRepository();
int adsOrderCnt = WebOrderHdRepository.WebOrderHd.Count();
```

When run above code, an error occur :

**The given key was not present in the dictionary.**

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

I guessed the error message say Asp.net can not find the PK field in WebOrderHd table,
but I am sure there is PK field.

Anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Thank You!

Stack Trace :

```
[KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +9619597
   Advantage.Data.Provider.AdsProviderManifest.GetStoreType(TypeUsage edmType) +2930
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.StructuralTypeMappingGenerator.MapTableColumn(EdmProperty property, DbTableColumnMetadata tableColumnMetadata, Boolean isInstancePropertyOnDerivedType, Boolean isKeyProperty) +60
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.PropertyMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmEntityType entityType, IEnumerable`1 properties, DbEntitySetMapping entitySetMapping, DbEntityTypeMappingFragment entityTypeMappingFragment, IList`1 propertyPath, Boolean createNewColumn) +1293
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.EntityTypeMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmEntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping) +496
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.GenerateEntityTypes(EdmModel model, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping) +122
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmModel model) +30
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo) +189
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +59
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +62
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +117
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +453
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +57
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +37
   System.Linq.Queryable.Count(IQueryable`1 source) +50
   SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers.ProductController.List(String category, Int32 page) in C:\Users\mark\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SportsStore\SportsStore.WebUI\Controllers\ProductController.cs:37
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +151
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8969117
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE WEBORDERHD ( 
      PICKNO Char( 9 ),
      STATION Char( 10 ),
      CUSTNO Char( 32 ),
      COMPANY Char( 35 ),
      BNAME Char( 255 ),
      ADDRESS1 Char( 30 ),
      ADDRESS2 Char( 30 ),
      CITY Char( 64 ),
      STATE Char( 2 ),
      ZIP Char( 10 ),
      SCOMPANY Char( 35 ),
      SNAME Char( 255 ),
      SADDRESS1 Char( 30 ),
      SADDRESS2 Char( 30 ),
      SCITY Char( 64 ),
      SSTATE Char( 2 ),
      SZIP Char( 10 ),
      SALESPN Char( 10 ),
      TAXRATE Numeric( 6 ,3 ),
      CERTIFICA Char( 10 ),
      TOTAL Numeric( 11 ,2 ),
      CONTACT Char( 15 ),
      TITLE Char( 10 ),
      PHONE Char( 17 ),
      FAX Char( 17 ),
      BEEPER Char( 17 ),
      FREIGHT Numeric( 11 ,2 ),
      FINVNO Char( 6 ),
      CUSTNOTE Memo,
      MEMO Memo,
      MODDATE Date,
      PRNDATE Date,
      SHIPVIA Char( 15 ),
      SHIPDATE Date,
      DATE Date,
      STATUS Char( 30 ),
      EMAIL Char( 128 ),
      TAX Numeric( 11 ,2 ),
      PAYTYPE Char( 20 ),
      PAYREF Char( 20 ),
      CCREF Char( 50 ),
      PK Char( 36 ),
      ORDTIME Char( 8 ),
      SHIPMETHOD Char( 30 ),
      PROCSTATUS Char( 20 ),
      CUSTOMERPONO Char( 50 ),
      CUSTOMERJOBNO Char( 50 ),
      CUSTOMERPOCONTACT Char( 50 ),
      CUSTOMERPOCOMMENT Memo,
      S_COUNTRY Char( 10 ),
      B_COUNTRY Char( 10 ),
      SHIPBRANCH Char( 3 )) IN DATABASE;
```

Comment: Stacktrace would help :)

Comment: What's the structure of your WebOrderHd DB table?  Could you add to your question the SQL that you get if you right click on the table in Data Architect and click Generate SQL Script?  (Or the relevant parts of it, at least.)

Comment: I added the structure too. Please help me out~

Comment: It's not clear from the CREATE TABLE statement that the primary key actually exists.  It should maybe be "PK Char(36) Primary Key,".  But the primary key could also be added later.  In any case, you might want to verify that it does exist.

Comment: Yes the primary key is PK field, Table type is ADT and Index Fields are PK and PICKNO Field.

Comment: Is that really all that is in your /Entities/WebOrderHd.cs at the moment, or did you omit some of it for brevity?  I ask because the failure point in the Stack Trace is GetStoreType, which although I don't use Entity Framework I am guessing maps between DB columns and entity properties.  So perhaps one of the types in the DB is tripping it up?  Not knowing EF my first recommendation would be trying with a really stripped down table and a stripped down entity, say just PK and some other column.  See if that works.  If not, try PK as an int.  See if that works.  Progressively see when it fails.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, for now that is all the code in /Entities/WebOrderHd.cs (I just omitted using * and namespace). And I tried define PK as int, but still have same error message... Do you have any idea I can try more? Thank you!

Comment: And the PK field contains GUID value.

Comment: Just out of interest, you could try giving PK in your entity class the actual Guid type.  I don't expect that'll resolve your issue, but worth a try anyway.  After that, I'd day just start from basics - forget about WebOrderHd for now, create a minimal table with an int primary key and maybe one other int column, make an entity for that minimal table, and try that.  If that works, you know your problem is specific to your WebOrderHd table.  If it doesn't work, then there's something wrong with how you're configuring EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I by no means am an expert at EF but... have you tried making the PK property virtual? My understanding is EF needs to create a proxy with your models so they have to be virtual so it can implement it the way it needs.

```
[Key]    
public virtual string PK { get; set; }
```

Also, I would recommend trying to access the data without an advanced pattern first that way you can verify the basics work. I always add a separate console project and test things in there as you don't have to create a whole page just to see the results.

Comment: Thank you, I tried "public virtual string PK { get; set; }" but still same error message show up. It is my first time using ASP.NET so I do not know how to do DB connection test simply. Now I am searching on Google for that ;p

Comment: Ah there in lies the problem then :P Also.. ASP.NET and MVC are different. Make sure when you google you look for "MVC 3" and C# it will help narrow down your searches. Here is a link that will help you get started with this.. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1 You can use the console app to initialize your database and grab the data out just like in the tutorial accept you dont load it in a webpage :)

Comment: I tried in console app, AdsConnection conn = new AdsConnection("Data Source=\\\\XXX.XX.XX.XX:6262\\DB_BACK\\SD.ADD;ServerType=REMOTE;User ID=AdsSys;Password=xxxxx") ... and it works well....  but still I don't know how make it work in Entity Framework Data Model ... =3